# Why does start_routine for pthread_create return void* and take void*

Tags: c, posix, pthreads

The function header for `pthread_create` looks like this:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t * thread, 
                   const pthread_attr_t * attr,
                   void * (*start_routine)(void *), 
                   void *arg);
```

I understand it all except that the function pointer for `start_routine` is of the form `void* (*fpointer) (void*)` which means it takes in a `void*` **and returns a `void*`**.

The `void*` parameter is just a way to pass in an argument to the `start_routine`, I get that part, but I don't understand why the function returns a `void*`? What code will even notice that return value?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From the documentation for [`pthread_create`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_create.html):

> The thread is created executing `start_routine` with `arg` as its sole argument. If the `start_routine` returns, the effect is as if there was an implicit call to `pthread_exit()` using the return value of `start_routine` as the exit status. Note that the thread in which `main()` was originally invoked differs from this. When it returns from `main()`, the effect is as if there was an implicit call to `exit()` using the return value of `main()` as the exit status.

And [`pthread_exit`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_exit.html):

> The `pthread_exit()` function terminates the calling thread and makes the value `value_ptr` available to any successful `join` with the terminating thread.

So if you do a `pthread_join` on a thread, the pointer it returns is passed back to the joining thread, allowing you to transmit information from the dying thread to another, living thread.

Answer (score 8):

From the [spec](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_create.html):

> If the `start_routine` returns, the
>   effect is as if there was an implicit
>   call to `pthread_exit()` using the
>   return value of `start_routine` as the
>   exit status.